# add a row in table the value should be the input from the forms

Tags: html, angular, forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJteT.png)

i have form contain 4 fields like
Name
Last name
email
role
and an button

if the button clicked the input to the above form should be added as the row in a table below

Name*
            
          
          
           
            
           Last name*
          
        
        
          
            
          Email address*
           
        
        
        
            
          Select role*

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_btn">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"><img src="assets/images/add.png" id="add_icon"></div>
            <div class="col" id="add" (click)="add()">Add user</div>

        </div>
    </button>
</form>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h4 >User list</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<table *ngFor="let add of addUser">
    <tr>
            <th id="name">Name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email address</th>
            <th id="role">Role</th>
            <th id="user">User</th>
            <th id="action">Actions</th>

          </tr>

          <tr  >
            <td>{{add.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{add.Lname}}</td>
            <td>{{add.Email}}</td>
            <td>{{add.Role}}</td>
            <td>{{add.User}}</td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript along with HTML for this program.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  <select name="role">
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="user">User</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addRow(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the form data
  const name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
  const last_name = document.querySelector('input[name="last_name"]').value;
  const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  const role = document.querySelector('select[name="role"]').value;

  // Create a new row
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${name}</td>
    <td>${last_name}</td>
    <td>${email}</td>
    <td>${role}</td>
  `;

  // Append the row to the table
  document.querySelector('table > tbody').appendChild(row);
}

// Add event listener to the submit button
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', addRow);
```